# Assertion Failed Error while compiling Bitcoin-QT application in QT framework?

Tags: c++, qt, cryptography, bitcoin, assertions

I am facing error while compiling bitcoin-qt application, I didn't understand what is the problem in main.cpp.

The error:

> /main.cpp:2985: bool InitBlockIndex(): Assertion `block.hashMerkleRoot
>   == uint256("0x7c0b21983dc5a17daeef4b6b936375b0a59f3414af7a1bf248d98209447a494b")'
>   failed.

The program has unexpectedly finished.
what is the problem? Please give some advice to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you creating an alt coin?

Comment: No, we are creating Bitcoin.

Comment: Assertions don't fail while compiling, they fail at runtime. You got this error while running it, not compiling it.

Comment: Yes sir, I got your point, yes i have getting this error on runtime, so what is the solution for that, how i can resolve that?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this solution?
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21303/creating-genesis-block

> The first time you run the compiled code (daemon or qt), it will say
>   "assertion failed". Just exit the program, go to config dir (under
>   AppData/Roaming), open the debug.log, get the hash after
>   "block.GetHash() = ", copy and paste it to the beginnig of main.cpp,
>   hashGenesisBlock. Also get the merkle root in the same log file, paste
>   it to the ... position in the following code, in LoadBlockIndex()
>
> assert(block.hashMerkleRoot == uint256("0x...")); recompile the code,
>   and genesis block created!
>
> BTW, don't forget to change "txNew.vout[0].nValue = " to the coin per
>   block you defined, it doesn't matter to leave as 50, just be
>   consistent with your coin per block (do this before adjust the hash
>   and m-root, otherwise they will be changed again).
>
> check https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0 for complete
>   info

It's for an altcoin, but it seems you've some problem with the genesis block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i already check that. actually i am using Ubuntu 14.04. In ubuntu how to resolve that issue.

Comment: I have found the debug.log file, but when i tried to search for hash "block.GetHash()=", i have not find any hash and even the merkleroot also, There is also another case when i delete debug.log file when i run again the bitcoin-qt application it will not create debug.log. It will created by Bitcoind server application.